# "The system cannot find the file specified" even though the file's dir is in %PATH%

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a file called `myfile.txt` and this file lives in `C:/files/myfile.txt`. I have `C:/files` in the `PATH` environment variable. When I do `echo %PATH%` I do in fact see `C:/files`. But when I try to do `type "myfile.txt"` it says `The system cannot find the file specified`. Also interestingly, an executable, like `C:/files/my_program.exe` works fine when I write just `my_program`. So why can Windows detect executables only, and not other file types in my directory?

Comment: Type `dpath /?` for the data file equivalent of `path`. Note the older name is `append` and the help still calls it that. This is depreciated since 1984 I think.

Comment: Is this something I have to do each time in a `cmd`? What is the point of `PATH` if I have to append the paths all over again?

Comment: It purpose is in MSDos Ver 2 and later to let MSDos Ver 1 programs find data files in subdirectories which only came in in Ver 2.

Comment: CMD can run any command on startup. See `cmd /?` (the `/d`) - `AutoRun` `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`

Comment: Please read the Microsoft article about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file). You can read there that the directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as used by you. So you should use in future the backslash character and not the slash character in file/folder paths. Next please read from top to bottom my answer on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

Comment: Also (to type just myfile) `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Myfile.EXE` `@="C:\files\myfile.txt"` (or to type myfile.txt)  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Myfile.txt` `@="C:\files\myfile.txt"` To use `start myfile`.

Comment: The `PATH` variable is intended to store paths to find *executables* (to be precise, those with a file name extension specified in `PATHEXT`); to find *data files* you can use `DPATH`, or simply specify the full file path...

Comment: Is it safe to do `set DPATH=%PATH%` ?

Comment: Yes it is. Although it is a security hole but then nothing would target it as nobody uses it.